# Should I do unit test in android development?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing

I have developed some app when I was a beginner, I was doing manual testing. Should I go for unit testing or instrumentation testing?

Comment: definitely ! :)

Comment: Take a look on TDD "Test-driven development",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should do it. There is no excuse to let it slide since Android is providing a nice UI Test Framework [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)

With simple code like this e.g.

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view))            // withId(R.id.my_view) is a ViewMatcher
        .perform(click())               // click() is a ViewAction
        .check(matches(isDisplayed())); // matches(isDisplayed()) is a ViewAssertion
```

and with the new [Espresso Test Recorder](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder.html) you can even record your test cases. It's still in beta, but it creates a handy code snippet which you can base your tests on.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test only use for method or class test. Thats are invisible items on Ui. But you will use espresso or ui automator test. Espresso depends on your ui code. Uiautomator never needs your ui code only use accessibility api and perform actions via this api.